# Camel CXF asynchronous request and reply

Tags: cxf, apache-camel

I would like to set up a Camel CXF endpont, and have the SOAP response asynchronous to much of my Camel Route. The route will have a lot of processing steps, and I do not want to have the response generated at the very end.

An example endpoint:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="someEndpoint"
                     address="/Service"
                     serviceClass="com.SomeImpl" />
```

An example route:

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("cxf:bean:someEndpoint")
        to("bean:processingStep1")
        to("bean:replyToSOAP")  // I would like to respond to cxf:cxfEndpoint here!
        to("bean:processingStep2")
        to("bean:processingStep3")
        to("bean:processingStep4");
        // The response to cxf:cxfEndpoint actually happens here.
    }
}
```

I have tried many options in MyRouteBuilder to "fork" the process (i.e. bean:replyToSOAP):

1. .multicast().parallelProcessing()
2. In-memory Asynchronous messaging ("seda" and "vm")
3. I have NOT tried JMS. It could be overkill for what I want to do.

I can get the route steps to process in parallel, but **all** steps must be completed before the response is generated.

In addition to the answer Claus gives below, I'd like to add that the placement of wireTap is important. Using:

```
.wireTap("bean:replyToSOAP")
```

will not get the desired behavior. What will is:

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("cxf:bean:someEndpoint")
        to("bean:processingStep1")
        .wireTap("direct:furtherProcessing")
        to("bean:replyToSOAP")  // respond to cxf:cxfEndpoint here

        from("direct:furtherProcessing") // steps happen independantly of beann:replyToSOAP 
        to("bean:processingStep2")
        to("bean:processingStep3")
        to("bean:processingStep4");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the WireTap EIP which can spin of a copy of the message to be processed independently from the current route: http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap